# Changing the structure of JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This question seems odd but am finding it difficult to convert the below given JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "NP",
        "description": "North Pit",
        "boxList": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Box1",
                "description": "First Box",              
                "locationId": 1,
                "benches": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Sample Bench",
                        "description": "Sample Bench"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Sample Bench1",
                        "description": "Sample Bench1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Box2",
                "description": "Second Box",             
                "locationId": 1,
                "benches": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Sample Bench",
                        "description": "Sample Bench"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Sample Bench1",
                        "description": "Sample Bench1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

into

```
[
    {
        "pit": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "SouthPit",
            "description": "South Description"
        },
        "boxList": [
            {
                "boxes": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Sample Box",
                    "description": "Sample Box"
                },
                "benchList": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Sample Bench1",
                        "description": "Sample Bench"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "boxes": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Sample Box",
                    "description": "Sample Box"
                },
                "benchList": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Sample Bench",
                        "description": "Sample Bench"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

wherein each object is a repeating object where there can be multiple boxes for a single pit or multiple benches for a pit.Can anybody throw some light .
I have tried to construct the JSON

```
  function constructPitData(data) {
                var firstLevel;
                var constructedPitDetails = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    firstLevel= {
                        id:data[i].pit.id,
                        name: data[i].pit.name,
                        desc: data[i].pit.description,
                        locId: data[i].pit.mineLocationId,
                        boxDetails:[]
                    }
                    constructedPitDetails.push(firstLevel);
                    constructBoxDetails(data, firstLevel);
                }
            }

            function constructBoxDetails(data, pit) {
                var boxFirstLevel;
                var constructedBoxDetails = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                    if (pit.id === data[j].pit.id) {
                        var newBox = {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @ MANOJ what you have done so far?

Comment: to get you started, your first step would be for every element in the input array, `for (var i=0,l=ain.length; i<l; i++) {`  create a new object and move into its pit field the contents of the element `var nwo = {};  nwo.pit = ain[i];` then move the boxlist out of the pit field `nwo.boxList = nwo.pit.boxList; delete nwo.pit.boxList;` and finally push the object into the output array `aou.push(nwo);`  then code similar movements for boxes and benches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to iterate over pits and boxes

your first step would be for every element in the input array,

```
for (var i=0,l=inputarray.length; i<l; i++) {
```

create a new object a

```
var newpit = {};
```

and move into its `pit` field the contents of the element

```
newpit.pit = inputarray[i];
```

then move the boxlist out of the pit field

```
newpit.boxList = newpit.pit.boxList;
delete newpit.pit.boxList;
```

and finally push the object into the output array

```
outputarray.push(newpit);
```

this ends step 1

now, you need to fix the boxList too, so code similar movements for each box in the boxlist

```
for (var j=0,n=newpit.pit.boxList.length; j<n; j++) {
```

create a new box element

```
var newbox = {};
```

and move the boxlist into the `boxes` field

```
newbox.boxes = newpit.pit.boxList[j];
```

and the benches out for the `boxes` and into a `benches` field

```
newbox.benches = newbox.boxes.benches;
delete newbox.boxes.benches;
```

finally push this new object

```
newpit.boxList.push(newbox);
```

and this ends step two

---

so, putting all the pieces together...

```
   var outputarray = [];
   for (var i=0,l=inputarray.length; i<l; i++) {
      var newpit = {};
      newpit.pit = inputarray[i];
      newpit.boxList = [];

      for (var j=0,n=newpit.pit.boxList.length; j<n; j++) {
        var newbox = {};
        newbox.boxes = newpit.pit.boxList[j];
        newbox.benches = newbox.boxes.benches;
        delete newbox.boxes.benches;
        newpit.boxList.push(newbox);       
      }
      delete newpit.pit.boxList;
      outputarray.push(newpit);

   }
```